# Add data in C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
private void btn_add_store_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Product values("+sa_code+",'" +pro_name+ "',"+quantity+",'"+price+"','"+notes+"')", con);
    con.Open();
        
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       
    con.Close();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the ' symbol in the " " string parts.

Comment: @Malekel Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not provide code as Image. Please include code and related error with StackTrace information.

Comment: You should copy an paste the code into the question instead of posting a picture.  Also it could be an issue with one of the values you concatenate into the query which is why you should really use parameters instead.

Comment: You have wrong sql syntax. `Insert into Products(code, proName...) values`

Comment: You should also include the list of column names with the table to make sure you're inserting the values in the correct order.

Comment: @panoskarajohn The syntax will work without the column list, however it's best practice to include it.

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing what the final composed value of the `CommandText` was, it is hard to comment specifically - as it will depend on the values being passed in, but ultimately the problem here **is that it depends on the values being passed in**. You should never concatenate values to create SQL, basically - it leaves you vulnerably to malicious SQL injection, or accidental bugs due to things like quotes in fields. There's also a secondary problem of the ambiguous column order. I **cannot advocate strongly enough** that you should use parameters here (and also name the columns); for example:

```sql
insert into Product (Code, ProductName, Quantity, Price, Notes)
values (@sa_code, @pro_name, @quantity, @price, @notes);
```

But then we need to pass those parameters *in*; a tool like Dapper would make this painless:

```cs
using Dapper; // at the top of the file
...
con.Execute(@"
insert into Product (Code, ProductName, Quantity, Price, Notes)
values (@sa_code, @pro_name, @quantity, @price, @notes);",
    new { sa_code, pro_name, quantity, price, notes });
```

Here, Dapper will deal with adding all the parameters for you; it will also handle opening and closing the connection on your behalf.

Comment: Not having single quotes around `sa_code` may be correct if it's an integer.

Comment: @juharr actually, looking again at the image, I might have been wrong about the quote, but: I maintain that this is still the right fix :)

Comment: @juharr rephrased for clarity

Comment: Oh definitely they should include the columns, and use parameters, I'm just saying it's hard to know the exact issue since the quotes are balanced and we don't know the types or the values being concatenated (which might include single quotes that are not escaped)

Comment: I tried the solution but errors appear
I modified the code and it worked successfully
This is the code:

 cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Product(Code, Name, Quantity, Price, Notes)values('"+sa_code.Text+ "','"+pro_name.Text+"','"+ quantity.Text + "','"+price.Text+"','"+notes.Text+"')", con);
            con.Open();
            
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

Comment: @MaleKel yeah, you've ignored everything I said; I cannot emphasize this enough: the approach you are using (concatenation) is incredibly dangerous; not only will it be brittle against bugs involving quotes, but it can be used to completely hack your database, including data corruption, deletion, and exfiltration.

Comment: It is not a disregard, but I did not understand you well and when I tried your solution, many errors appeared @MarcGravell

Comment: @MaleKel if you'd talk to me about the specific errors you saw, we can probably help you; again: to be clear, what you have now is *actively dangerous*

Answer (score 0):

```
 cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Product(Code, Name, Quantity, Price, Notes)values('"+sa_code.Text+ "','"+pro_name.Text+"','"+ quantity.Text + "','"+price.Text+"','"+notes.Text+"')", con);
        con.Open();
        
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

//this is the right answer